# load balancing issue in websphere 8.5.5

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-8, application-server

I am working on clustering project with websphere 8.5.5 network deployment version.
But I am asking to know what to install as a load balancer.

is IHS 8.5.5 enough or should I install something else ?

Answer (score 1):

Typical architecture might contain hardware or software additional load balancers.
In general, one IHS works as a load balancer as well.

Please look at the following link [Load balancer](http://www.webspheretools.com/sites/webspheretools.nsf/docs/WebSphere+Cluster+versus+Load+Balance)

Comment: so If I am using network deployment version then installing the IHS with the same version will work fine?

Thanks in advanced

Comment: another question please 
Why do we need to use websphere plugin to connect to IHS 8.5
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/doc.1111/e29751/ihs_80.htm

while in IHS 7 we used the console directly
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/doc.1111/e29751/ihs_61.htm

Comment: You need a plugin in order to manage web-server from one console. If you look into documentation carefully installers do the same thing (install a server and configure a plugin).  Plugin configuration becomes as an option of installer starting from 8 version.

Comment: also look at session affinity in websphere, it's another element to consider

Answer (score 1):

You usually install following architecture:

LB -> 2xIHS -> NxWAS

where

- LB - is a Load Balancer - it can be a hardware one or, if customer doesn't have any balancer you can use software Load Balancer from Edge components package from WebSphere Network Deployment edition. LB should also be highly available. The software one provider with WAS ND works in Active/Standby mode, where standby node monitors active one and takes over, when it fails.
- IHS - is IBM Http Server, with Plugin installed - you usually install at least 2 to have HA. Plugin handles session affinity and reroutes, if any of WAS servers is down. Because Plugin handles that LB can be simpler and may just balance across IHS servers
- WAS - is WebSphere App Server - you create cluster there and install your application in the cluster.

Comment: what do you mean by edge component package. as I have ND version and thought I should use IHS as load balancer between them .
is there a way to load balance using the ND package itself ?
@gas

Comment: You can use IHS, but then it will become a SPOF. So you usually place two of them, and then need some balancer to distribute traffic among IHSes. If you have ND license, then as separate download you will have Edge components', from where you can install software load balnacer - http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7K4U_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.edge.doc/lbip4/nd6mst08.html%23int?lang=en